# A recognition error occurred while using StartsWith in Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am facing the following exception when executing a query with StartsWith over odata. I am using web API 2 to access SQL server database using Nhibernate

```html
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code/>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">An error has occurred.</m:message>
<m:innererror>
<m:message>
 The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.
</m:message>
<m:type>System.InvalidOperationException</m:type>
<m:stacktrace/>
<m:internalexception>
<m:message>
 A recognition error occurred. [.Where[CamConnect.Entities.Entities.TradeView](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[CamConnect.Entities.Entities.TradeView], Quote(($it, ) => (Equal(Equal(Or(Equal($it.Cusip_Number, NULL), p1) ? NULLp3 : Convert($it.Cusip_Number.StartsWith(p2, )), p4), p5))), )]
</m:message>
<m:type>NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException</m:type>
<m:stacktrace>
 at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ErrorCounter.ThrowQueryException()
 at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlTranslator.Translate()
 at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.DoCompile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow, String collectionRole)
 at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode ast, String queryIdentifier, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
 at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryExpressionPlan..ctor(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
 at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
 at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
 at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
 at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
 at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
 at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
 at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataFeedSerializer.WriteFeed(Object graph, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
 at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataFeedSerializer.WriteObject(Object graph, ODataMessageWriter messageWriter, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
 at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.<>c__DisplayClassa.<WriteToStreamAsync>b__9()
 at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously(Action action, CancellationToken token)
</m:stacktrace>
</m:internalexception>
</m:innererror>
</m:error>
```

**My Query:**

```
   var q = container.TradeView.Where(x => x.Cusip_Number.StartsWith("78"));
        var count = q.Count();
        Assert.IsTrue(count > 0);
```

Comment: have you checked how StartsWith() is translated to query?